# Lua Error: "attempt to call a string value" under Android NDK?

Tags: android, android-ndk, lua

My Lua scripts are compiled by [LOOP](http://loop.luaforge.net/release/preload.html), the compiled scripts module runs well in a desktop machine(OSX 10.7.5). But when I run it under Android phone (Android 2.3.6), it always fails and complains `attempt to call a string value`. The same scripts can run also without problems in script (not compiled) way in the same phone.

Lua 5.1.5 and Android NDK r8b are used in the test.

The error in logcat:

```
12-26 09:40:26.934: E/libb22luapre(8190): Failed to run script: attempt to call a string value
```

The C code snippet (error handling code removed for simplicity):

```c
const char script[] = "require \"hello.world\"\n"
            "require \"anothermodule\"\n"
            "hello.world.test2()";
luaL_loadstring(L, script);
lua_pcall(L, 0, LUA_MULTRET, 0);
```

I dumped the preloaded table, these required modules already exists (loaded successfully).

I searched the web, still can not find a solution. Any advice will be greatly appreciated.

[UPDATED]
I compiled lua command for android and embed the compiled lua scripts in it. The error is just the same as above.

```
$ adb shell
$ cd /data/local
$ ls
tmp
lua
dump_preload.lua
$ ./lua dump_preload.lua
--- print table --- preload
    test    function: 0x376f0
    anothermodule   function: 0x37718
    hello.world function: 0x376b0
--- print table --- loaded
    string  table: 0x33828
    debug   table: 0x37098
    package table: 0x33d30
    _G  table: 0x32528
    io  table: 0x34e80
    os  table: 0x357b8
    table   table: 0x332c0
    math    table: 0x36530
    coroutine   table: 0x33988
--- print table --- loaders
    1   function: 0x33ed8
    2   function: 0x33ef8
    3   function: 0x33f18
    4   function: 0x33f38
$ ./lua
Lua 5.1.5  Copyright (C) 1994-2012 Lua.org, PUC-Rio
> require 'test'
attempt to call a string value
stack traceback:
    [C]: ?
    [C]: in function 'require'
    stdin:1: in main chunk
    [C]: ?
> require 'hello.world'
attempt to call a string value
stack traceback:
    [C]: ?
    [C]: in function 'require'
    stdin:1: in main chunk
    [C]: ?
>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem resolved. It turns out that the compiled lua code are not portable. You must compile lua scripts against a target machine.

A short summary for the steps:

1. Compile lua command for Android
2. Push the lua command file and LOOP's lua files and your app's lua files into a folder in the target phone, say, /data/local
3. Open adb shell and compile lua script files
4. Pull out the generated .h .c files